# Differences in collections implementations between 32 bit and 64 bit, any pitfalls we need to worry about?

Tags: java, java-8, 32bit-64bit

We have a 32 bit client process that communicates via CORBA to a legacy server application running on a remote machine. This has run well and reliably for about 12 years.

We needed to (temporarily) switch our client process to 64 bit to get more memory (pending an imminent rewrite) and almost immediately ran into some problems with the **remote** application. The process crashed repeatedly. Initially this made no sense, how can a remote application be sensitive to a client application VM if it uses a platform agnostic protocol such as CORBA?

After a couple of days investigation we found that the remote process crashing has nothing to do with the client VM but does appear to be down to the ordering of parameters we send.

We send an array of requested result types to the server, this is originally taken from config and put into a HashSet, converting to an array at the last minute. The server application appears to be sensitive to the order of the requested result types.

E.g. If we send PV (0), DELTA (1), NPV (2), GAMMA (3) it's fine. If we send GAMMA (3), PV (0), DELTA (1), NPV(2) the remote application crashes. This just appears to be a weird bug in the remote application that has never been exposed before because the order has always been numeric (by chance).

It's the switch to 64 bit that appeared to make the difference, the 64 bit version produces a different ordering of elements from the HashSet. This isn't something I expected but I suspect that HashCodes are only deterministic on a platform basis.

Ensuring that the array is sorted before sending has fixed the issue. Switching to a TreeSet would help as well but thats deep in a library somewhere.

Are there any other oddities between 32 bit and 64 bit we need to worry about? So far, I've been impressed as to how easy the conversion was, no other code changes at all.

At the moment we are on Java 6 and the move to Java 8 is imminent. Can we expect similar issues when moving to Java 8?

Comment: I think that is almost impossible to tell. If other areas of your application depend on the same or similar behavior that is deterministic only by accident(!), then you could even be bitten by similar problems between point releases of Java.

Comment: I can't speak for Java, but I can tell you that in C#, when MSFT implemented 64 bit versions there was zero impact to questions like this.  The reason is that the main differences in 32 and 64 bit applications are in addressiblity, not function. The registers at the hardware layer have more room, they are not 4 bytes any longer they are 8 bytes.  But in order to accomodate legacy apps. there were some unique things that had to happen, for example there are two registries, two program file paths etc. But the IDEs handled it perfectly. Mostly transparent to the developer.

Comment: The hashCode doesn't depend on 32-bit/64-bit, it will always be the same, as will the behaviour of HashSet.  What might change is if you switch from an old version of Java to a much newer version which supports 64-bit.  Note: you can get more memory by just running a 32-bit JVM on a 64-bit OS, instead of a 32-bit OS.  This will minimise the number of changes.

Comment: We switched from 1.6u45 32 bit to u45 64 bit. Same version and we definitely saw differences which I didn't expect. We're desperate to get off Java 6 but we needed to update all our hoss from older versions of RHEL first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, Java bytecode is platform-independent. You can run the same bytecode on a 32-bit or 64-bit JVM; you do not need to recompile your code for a specific platform.

Implementations of `Map` in general do not have a specified iteration order, so you should not write programs that depend on the order of elements in for example a `HashMap`. If you do that, as you have discovered, then there is a bug in your application. If you need a specific iteration order, use for example `LinkedHashMap` (which keeps the elements in insertion order) or `TreeMap` (which keeps the elements sorted, using whatever criteria you specify).

It's possible that if there is more memory available (for example because you use a 64-bit JVM instead of a 32-bit JVM, with different memory settings), `HashMap` behaves differently. It's also possible that if you use a slightly different JVM version (for example, Java 6 update X instead of Java 6 update Y) the iteration order will be different.

There is no list anywhere that lists the implementation-specific changes. If you write Java programs that depend undocumented implementation details of a specific Java version, then it's ofcourse possible that your program won't work anymore on any other Java version.

Oracle has a [Compatibility Guide for JDK 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html) which explains in which ways exactly Java 8 has minor incompatibilities with previous versions, but this only covers changes in the Java API, not implementation details.

If you do upgrade from Java 6 to Java 8 (which is recommended anyway, because Java 6 is no longer supported), then test your programs before you put them into production.

Comment: The byte code independence is pretty awesome. We deserialised some old files created with very old Java versions and it worked perfectly. As discussed above, we are upgrading to 8 and needed to upgrade RHEL first. That's the hardest part.